# Reducing Jitter on Ubuntu 15.04 low latency

Tags: 15.04

Using ubuntu 15.04 I see jitter of around 10-11 micro-seconds every 1000 micro-seconds.

I have graphed the distribution of jumps of at least 1 micro-second on i7-3970X with low latency Ubuntu 15.04.  The program is spinning on RDTSC and recording jumps to an array to printed at the end.

[image]

There appears to be two modes of 1 milli-seconds and around 60 - 75 micro-seconds.

There are times when there is no such jitter for hundreds of millis-seconds.

I am using

```
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-22-lowlatency root=UUID=f5747871-dfe2-46bf-b6e5-a6cd474adaf7 
ro  quiet splash isolcpus=2,3,8,9 $vt_handoff
```

And I am binding to the cpu 2 which is isolated.  IrqBalance is off. My power management is set to performance.  I have tried using `chrt` but this hasn't helped.

Does anyone recognise this behaviour? Is there a way to know a way to diagnose it and fix this?

All I am doing is spinning on RDTSC on one CPU.

EDIT: I have also tried adding `intel_pstate=disable` but this didn't seem to help.

@mjpt777 suggested I look at `idle=poll`, something which at first glance makes it worse, except looking at the worst 50% of delays, it is much improved.

With `idle=poll` , graphing the length of the delay

[image]

This is clearly is something the kernel is doing.  Is this further tunable? i.e. does it have to happen every milli-second?  Linux should be tickless, but it appears to be not fully tickless.

```
$ grep NO_HZ /boot/config-3.19.0-22-lowlatency 
CONFIG_NO_HZ_COMMON=y
CONFIG_NO_HZ_IDLE=y
# CONFIG_NO_HZ_FULL is not set
CONFIG_NO_HZ=y
CONFIG_RCU_FAST_NO_HZ=y
```

I have added `nohz_full=` and `rcu_nocbs=` and these appear to help but the frequency of jitter hasn't changed.

@DougSmythies suggested I revert back to the generic kernel and this significantly reduced the number of interrupts as their length.

Here is a sample of the space between interrupts (note they are not all 4000 micros, and they are shorter in length) See my answer.

Comment: microseconds?  That's peanuts!  What are you doing that requires such extremely low latency?

Comment: Your CPU 2 still has to service interrupts. Specifically the jiffy based tick interrupt, which will still occur because the CPU is active. I think if you try the generic kernel (250 Hz instead of 1000 Hz) you will find that what you are calling "jumps" will change to every 4000 microseconds from 1000 microseconds.

Comment: @Daniel I have a fix engine which reads a message, writes the message to as mmap, parses the message, generates a response, writes that to a mmap file and sends the response in ~ 2.5 micro-seconds 85% of the time.  This is useful work.  However, the kernel interrupts the process for 5 - 10 micro-second delay for no good reason I can work out.  It's a bit sad that Java is not the latency outlier but instead it's the kernel.

Comment: @DougSmythies I wondered about this. Do you know how to revert the kernel? It appears the generic version was uninstalled when I installed the low latency one.

Comment: @DougSmythies I was hoping that NO_HZ_FULL and adaptive interrupts wouldn't interrupt a CPU which has only one runnable thread.

Comment: @DougSmythies what would happen if the CPU didn't service interrupts at all. e.g. say it was running one thread and not doing anything else.

Comment: @DougSmythies switching from "lowlatency" to "generic" reduced the number of interrupts > 1 us from 85K to 7K over 85 second. Better than a factor of 4.

Comment: 85K to 7K: I would not have expected that. Interesting. NO_Hz_FULL: The jiffy based timer will still run, if the CPU is active on a jiffy boundary. If the CPU is idle on a jiffy boundary then it will not run, but rather be deferred. My understanding of how you are doing your testing is that CPU 2 is 100% busy,

Comment: @DougSmythies You are right it is 100% busy doing something useful but it keeps getting interrupted. If it gets interrupted 85K times or 7K times, it still appears to work which suggests at least 90% of those interrupts are not needed and I suspect something close to 100% are redundant.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that in this situation, the `-generic` kernel has less spurious interrupts than the `-lowlatency` kernel. The boot command line parameters and machine are the same.

In 85 seconds, the low latency kernel interrupted a test 85K times, whereas the generic kernel interrupted it 7K times.  Additionally the length of the interrupts were shorter.

[image]

The low latency kernel is above 2.5 us all the time whereas the generic kernel is above 2 us about 20% of the time.

[image]

Comment: I am not completely sure how to interpret the x-axis, but your first graph does, I think, still suggest a basic jiffy based interrupt, just not on every jiffy. Some are every jiffy, some every 2 and some every 3, for a total of 7k in the 85 seconds.

Comment: @DougSmythies That is how I read it. 7% of interrupts are sub jitffy (for a 4000 us jiffy) the rest are either 1x, 2x not more than 3x the jiffy.

Comment: I re-worked a very old gap measuring tool that I wrote many years ago. Things have gotten so much better, as my old threshold for considering it a "gap" was 45 milliseconds. Anyway, I used a threshold of greater than 2 uSecs and got (usecs count): 3 3279; 4 155; 5 15; 6 3; 7 117231; 8 257641; 9 766; 10 98; 11 10; 12 2; 13 1. I got times between occurrences all  over the place, including 142 at greater than 0.2 seconds. My numbers were dominated by N * 4000 uSec. I suspect that the tick based interrupt always runs, but sometimes has nothing to do  and so returns quickly, below the threshold.